# Finding 2 highest value in a row using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have numbers 5, 3, 1, 8, 7 in a row in mysql table and each number belongs to a column.

How do I find the two highest number and find its sum?

Comment: Are the numbers always unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming the table name is `coltb` and it has the following successive columns

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
```

you can issue the following statement to get the 2 highest numbers:

```
select col1 from coltb union select col2 from coltb union select col3 from coltb union select col4 from coltb union select col5 from coltb order by col1 desc limit 2;
```